# Why is my controller getting back an empty viewmodel from view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a viewmodel:

```
public class ProductInShopsCheckboxViewModel
    {
        public ProductInShop? ProductInShop { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<ProductInShop>? Checkboxes { get; set; }
    }
```

view(that works):

```
@model WebApp.ViewModels.ProductInShopsCheckboxViewModel
@if (Model?.Checkboxes != null) {
    <h4>@Model.Checkboxes!.ElementAt(0).Shop!.ShopName</h4>
    <p></p>
    <form asp-action="Create">
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Checkboxes!.Count(); i++) {
            <input type="checkbox" asp-for="Checkboxes.ElementAt(i).IsSelected">@Model.Checkboxes.ElementAt(i).Product?.ProductName
            <p></p> }
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Send email" class="btn btn-primary"/>
        </div>
    </form> }
<p></p>
<a asp-action="Index">Back to Shops</a>
```

and controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create(ProductInShopsCheckboxViewModel vm)
        {
            //TODO: check which vm.Checkboxes items are selected
            //Send those items to mail(code ready)
        }
```

However I get back viewmodel with empty list and I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong. I appreciate any advice.

Comment: I think you are missing @ in:
asp-for="@Checkboxes.ElementAt(i).IsSelected" Check what HTML is generated in view.

Comment: No difference in generated html or controller behavior

Comment: Change IEnumerable to List, use indexes in for loop, add to form method="post" and should work.